# react-router history and typescript not working - Overload 1 of 2, '(props: RouterProps | Readonly<RouterProps>): Router'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router

I am simplifying trying to setup history with react-router-dom but for some reason TS does not like me in this regard!

### history.ts

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
export default createBrowserHistory();
```

### root/app.tsx

```
import { Router } from 'react-router-dom';

import { Routes } from 'Routes';

import history from 'routerHistory';

function App() {
  return (
      <Router history={history}>
        <Header />
        <Routes />
      </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

### TS Error

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: RouterProps | Readonly<RouterProps>): Router', gave the following error.
    Type 'BrowserHistory<State>' is missing the following properties from type 'History<unknown>': length, goBack, goForward
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: RouterProps, context: any): Router', gave the following error.
    Type 'BrowserHistory<State>' is not assignable to type 'History<unknown>'.  TS2769

    15 |       <ToastContainer />
    16 |       <GlobalStyle />
  > 17 |       <Router history={history}>
       |               ^
    18 |         <Header />
    19 |         <Routes />
    20 |       </Router>
```

Comment: Can you show the contents of your `package.json` and `tsconfig.json` files? At the first glance it looks live types mismatch. `react-router-dom` uses the exact type from `history` package _in normal circumstances_.

Comment: any solutions??

Comment: I believe I had the wrong version. Which has breaking changing in the new version. So check you have the correct verion in the docs.

Answer (score 2):

To anyone still having this issue, it is related to incompatible versions within the `package.lock.json` file. I found that using the following combination in your `package.json` works:

```
"react-router-dom": "6.3.0",
"history": "5.2.0"
```

If this doesn't work for you, but you have a working version that breaks whenever you delete the `package.lock.json` file, here is how to solve it:

- open your `package.lock.json` file
- search for `react-router-dom`
- note down the version of `react-router-dom` and it's dependency's version of `history`
- add those two version to your root `package.json` file (without `^` at the version beginning, to lock down the working versions)